# How to Nginx rewrite and change capitalization of arguments?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, lua

I need to perform an Nginx permanent redirect, and also change the capitalization of the arguments.

Currently the rewrite rule looks like that:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/old_url/(.*)/(.*).html$ "http://cdn.example.com/test/$1 $2.pdf" permanent;
}
```

What I tried was to change the capitalization using Lua, and then pass `$var1` and `$var2` to rewrite second argument:

```
set_by_lua $var1 "return ngx.arg[1]:lower()" $1;
set_by_lua $var2 "return ngx.arg[1]:lower()" $2;
```

However it doesn't work, as `$1` and `$2` are accessible only in the rewrite directive scope.

What would be the right way to handle the redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is the solution:

```
location ~* /old_url/(.*)/(.*).html {
    set_by_lua $var1 "return ngx.arg[1]:upper()" $1;
    set_by_lua $var2 "return ngx.arg[1]:upper()" $2;
    return 301 "http://cdn.example.com/test/$var1 $var2.pdf";
}
```

Instead of matching the URL using the `rewrite`, `location` is used. Then `$1` and `$2` are accessible in the scope and can be modified with Lua.